# ActiveRecord query differs when using string or instance variable

Tags: ruby, activerecord

If you view the query, `@bot_client_id` is a string with the same value of `string`.  However, I get different results when using them as part of my query.

Why?

```
[24] pry(#<BotResponse>):1> string
=> "aiaas-1409611358153-user-0149"

[25] pry(#<BotResponse>):1> @bot_client_id
=> "aiaas-1409611358153-user-0149"

[26] pry(#<BotResponse>):1> Event.where.has{(status == 'active') & (bot_client_id == @bot_client_id)}
=> []
[27] pry(#<BotResponse>):1> Event.where.has{(status == 'active') & (bot_client_id == string)}
=> [#<Event:0x0000000464d120
  id: 22,
  bot_client_id: "aiaas-1409611358153-user-0149",
  keyword: "gratitude",
  topic: nil,
  status: "active",
  channel: "telegram",
  created_date: 2017-05-09 15:56:51 UTC,
  tickle_expression: "daily",
  time_of_day: "7:00 am",
  next_occurrence: 2017-05-14 14:00:00 UTC,
  time_zone: "America/Los_Angeles",
  recurring: true>,
 #<Event:0x0000000464cfb8
  id: 23,
  bot_client_id: "aiaas-1409611358153-user-0149",
  keyword: "daily_check",
  topic: nil,
  status: "active",
  channel: "telegram",
  created_date: 2017-05-10 04:25:47 UTC,
  tickle_expression: "daily",
  time_of_day: "9:00 am",
  next_occurrence: 2017-05-14 16:00:00 UTC,
  time_zone: "America/Los_Angeles",
  recurring: false>]
```

Comment: What does `@bot_client_id.class` return? I ask because that `@bot_client_id` returns a string in the console, does not necessarily mean that it is a string. It's `inspect` or `to_s` method might just be overridden.

Comment: What is this `.has` method? Is it from activerecord or some additional library?

Comment: It returns a string class. Is checked that as well.

Comment: .has is from the baby squeel gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
Event.where.has{(status == 'active') & (bot_client_id == @bot_client_id)}
```

`has` takes a block where `status` and `bot_client_id` are called. It seems unlikely for these two methods to be defined in an outside context.

Let's see what happens when we try to call a block with undefined variables:

```
>> def method_calling_block
|    yield
|  end #=> :method_calling_block

>> method_calling_block { abcd }
NameError: undefined local variable or method `abcd' for main:Object
    from (irb):44:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):40:in `method_calling_block'
    from (irb):44
    from /Users/fylooi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

If we don't call the block:

```
>> def method_without_calling_block
|  end #=> :method_without_calling_block

>> method_without_calling_block { abcd }  #=> nil
```

Looks like variables passed into a block are only evaluated when the block is processed (normally using `yield` or `block.call`). Looks like this block isn't handled the normal way.

A bit of googling reveals that `.where.has{}` is a method belonging to 
[BabySqueel](https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel). The BabySqueel documentation states that:

> BabySqueel's blocks use instance_eval, which means you won't have access to your instance variables or methods.

The relevant method appears to be `evaluate` in https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel/blob/master/lib/baby_squeel/dsl.rb

```
module BabySqueel
  class DSL < Relation
    def evaluate(&block)
      if block.arity.zero?
        instance_eval(&block)
      else
        yield(self)
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

This means that in the context of

```
Event.where.has{(status == 'active') & (bot_client_id == @bot_client_id)}
```

`@bot_client_id` is evaluated within the receiver's binding (which is a `BabySqueel::DSL` object) instead of the caller's binding. Naturally, it returns `nil`.

To force the block to be evaluated the usual way (ie. using variables bound to the caller), you need to make `block.arity.zero?` evaluate to `false` by passing an argument to it.

```
Event.where.has{|event| (event.status == 'active') & (event.bot_client_id == @bot_client_id)}
```

Comment: Ah I think you got it. Well described. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `has {}` method is a closure which changes of rubies `self` scope. You could see it via following command:

```
p self
Event.where.has{ p self; (status == 'active') & (bot_client_id == @bot_client_id) }
```

If outputs are different that means `@bot_client_id` in second execution returns nil.